# List View and ListActivity question in Android

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I am trying to use List View and List activity. My code is very simple, here are my java and xml files. The MyRecords.java file is:

```
public class MyRecords extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myrecords);
               .
               .
               .
```

myrecords.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:id="@+id/myrecords">
</TextView>
```

and I have added this to the Manifest file:

```
    <activity android:name=".MyRecords"
        android:label="@string/myrecords_title" >
    </activity>
```

in my main activity page I have a button corresponding to MyRecords. 
The problem is that as soon as I press the button the application force closes.
I appreciate any help in letting me know what is wrong with this code.
I must mention that when instead of ListActivity, I had activity, there was no problem with the code.

Thanks for the help.

TJ1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ListActivity needs to be supplied a layout that contains a ListView with the correct id (I think it's android:id/list).

Comment: It is `android:id/list`. @TJ1 - see the [docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Comment: Thanks you very much, that was it, so I changed:

Comment: I changed android:id="@+id/myrecords" to android:id="@android:id/list" and also added a ListView in the xml file, thanks again.